# How to remake the program so that words are passed in function arguments in the KOTLIN programming language?

Tags: kotlin

Need to create a function that implements the attached algorithm, to which all words are passed in the function arguments.

For example:
**f ("dfd" dd "ddd");**

My code:

```
    fun main() {
    var s = readLine();
    var w = Array(128){0} //To mark characters from a word 1
    var g = Array(128){0}//When we encounter a space, we add units from the first array to the corresponding elements of the second, zeroing them in the first.
    if(s!=null)
    {
        for(c in s)
        {
            if(c.toInt() > 127 || c.toInt()<0) {
                println("Input error, try again");
                return;
            }
            //Checking for space.
            if(c.toInt() != 32) w[c.toInt()] = 1;
            else
                for(k in 0..127)
                {
                    if(w[k] == 1)
                    {
                        g[k] += 1;
                        w[k]  = 0;
                    }
                }
        }
        //For the last word, if there was no space after it.
        for(k in 0..127)
        {
            if(w[k] == 1)
            {
                g[k] += 1;
                w[k]  = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    //Displaying matched characters to the screen
    for(k in 0..127)
    {
        if(g[k]>1)
        {
            println(k.toChar());
        }
    }
}
```

This program searches for characters that match at least two words in a string

**Example**

- **input:** hello world
- **output**: lo

Comment: Thanks for asking, in order to get the right answer, could you please give us more information about what have you tried and what is a specific issue/ error you are encountering? Please refer to question asking guidelines at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: May I ask where you got this code? It looks almost like C. There's probably a better way to solve it in Kotlin.

Comment: @user They mentioned on another question that it's converted from Python. Since this question is just asking how to write a function that has a parameter, I think OP has not read anything about Kotlin syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's already utilities for these in Kotlin, I highly recommend you to read the docs before asking these type of questions.

The [groupingBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html) should do what you want:

```kotlin
readLine()?.let { input ->
    input.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
        .forEach { if (it.value > 1 && it.key != ' ') println(it.key) }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not entirely correct, because the function should be called in this way

 nameFunction ("hello", "worlld")
 result = l, O

You need to use vararg to solve this problem, but I don't quite understand how