# How to transform this code using a functional approach in the Kotlin programming language

Tags: kotlin

I need to transform this code using a functional approach in the Kotlin language, while it is forbidden to use mutable collection and var variables, except for input and output

The attached code does the following

Schaeffer's bitwise stroke of the penultimate digit of all numbers (opera-
walkie-talkies are performed from right to left)

```
    fun main() {
    try {
        val s = readLine();
        var digits: Array<Int> = emptyArray();
        if (s != null) {
            var words = s.split(" ");
            for (c in words) {
                digits += (c.toInt() / 10) % 10
            }
            digits.reverse();
            var d = 0;
            while (digits.size - 1 != d) {

                println("Sheffer's stroke between ${digits[d]} и ${digits[d + 1]} = ${(digits[d] and digits[d + 1]).inv()}");
                d++

            }
        }
    } catch (s: NumberFormatException) {
        println("Input error please try again!")
    } catch (s: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        println("Out of bounds of an array")
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll leave the question of what ‘Schaeffer's Stroke’ might be (the [Sheffer stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke)?), as that's probably not too relevant.  Can you describe in words _what_ the existing code is intended to do (without going into _how_ it does it, which we can see)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```kotlin
readLine()?.let { input ->
    input.split(" ")
        .map { it.toInt() / 10 % 10 }
        .asReversed()
        .zipWithNext { a, b ->
            println("Sheffer's stroke between $a и $b = ${(a and b).inv()}")
        }
}
```

Of course you can wrap it around a `try-catch` block to handle the errors.

Here's a summary of what we've did there:

- `?.let` - runs the given block when value of the left is not null.
- `split(" ")` - splits the given input string with space delimiter.
- `map` - applies given block to each element of the list and returns a new list with returned value.
- `asReversed()` - returns a wrapper in which list is indexed from last to first (does not reallocate new memory or actually reverse the order), you can use `reversed()` to copy the contents inside list and make a reversed order list.
- `zipWithNext` - Calls the given block with two adjacent elements at a time, then returns list of returned items which is `Unit` in our case and useless.

Comment: Thank you very much, maybe you can help with a couple more questions? 1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013157
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64011457

Comment: It is necessary to make a sheffer's stroke between all the numbers, and not just between the adjacent ones, I was mistaken, example
123 3454 6767 78789 -> (((8and6) .inv ()) and5.inv ()) and2.inv ()))

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {
    val s = readLine();
    if(s!=null) {
        val input = s.split("")
                .map { it.toInt() / 10 % 10 }
            //    .asReversed()
                .reduceRight{total,next->(total and next).inv()}

        println(input)
    }
}
```